# Destroy Resources i don't need from asset resources

Tags: unity-game-engine

i have an app in which i store atlases for all the iOS devices.

I would like, on first load, to destroy all atlases from the app build so that i may save space on the device (i.e. currently, my app has almost 1 gb, by deleting unused atlases i go to around max 500 mb for iPad retina).

How can i do so?

Comment: Intersting question. I don't think it possible however. What about deploy the application without atlases and download just the desired ones on the first application run?

Comment: The application bundle as downloaded from the appstore is readonly. Also Unity has no methods for writing to or modifying the contents of the resources package. What you could do is only have low rez assets in the app and if the user has an iPad retina device ask if they want to download the hi rez art assets (using Unity's asset bundles). But you'd have to pay for the hosting and downloading of the big bundle, which wouldn't be worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have *Core features* & *Models* into your final package.
The use Asset bundles to download extra files from your hosted server. That is the same what people do.

Although, there is service provided by Google Play Store of spliting APK package into smaller files, called OBB. Then host those files in *Expansion pack* section onto *Google Play Server* when uploading APK. I don't, if the same kind of service is providing my Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets() http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets.html